# HTML in Shell Scripting UNIX

Tags: unix

```
val=Mumbai

cat << 'EOF' > pkll1.htm
<html> 
<head>
<title>HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>$val</h1>
while read line
do
val1=`echo $line`
<p>$val1</p>
done<myfile.dat
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

Above code showing output as below instead of actual value:

```
$val
while read line do val1=`echo $line` 
$val1

done
```

How to execute it in correct way?Help me please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it in separate blocks, with the code in the middle.

```
val=Mumbai
file=pkll1.htm

cat <<EOF1 > $file
<html> 
<head>
<title>HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>$val</h1>
EOF1

while read line; do
  val1=`echo $line`
  echo "<p>$val1</p>" >> $file
done < myfile.dat

cat <<EOF2 >> $file
</body>
</html>
EOF2
```

Comment: Note that the `cat << EOF` syntax treats any content up to the `EOF` line as input to the `cat` command (this will work for other commands as well). Therefore, no commands or unescaping is being performed on the text. This is like the `"""..."""` syntax in python -- python does not execute any code within that block. This explains why @pkawar's shell script does not work as intended.

Comment: Yes, and it's why I used separate chunks terminated by EOF1 and EOF2 instead.